# Unable to create a branch in subversion using TortoiseSVN

Tags: authentication, svn, branch, gssapi

Unable to create a branch in subversion using TortoiseSVN.

I get the following error message:

SVN authorization failed: could not authenticate to proxy server: ignored basic challenge, GSSAPI authentication error

Source URL:
"http://svn.lsc.co.uk/svn/projects/CWE/CWEConfig/trunk"

Traget URL:
"http://svn.lsc.co.uk/svn/projects/CWE/CWEConfig/branches/12c"

Comment: The * SVN authorization failed* tells me that you might have read, but not copy permission, or you're attempting to create the branch in the wrong location. A bit more info would be nice. For example, what does the URL of the original and what is the URL of the branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseSVN was not passing my credentials to proxy server, hence the request was being blocked there. Supplying credentials in Network > Proxy Settings resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure You have the read/write access for Both trunk and Branch location.